# Laravel 5.2 get the closest date from eloquent collection

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I have Eloquent Event model, which is related towards multiple dates like this:

```
$event->dates // shows Collection of 8 Eloquent date models
```

After that i need to pick the only date, what is closest to current time. I know how to do this using query of raw SQL, or DB class. But isnt there any better solution? I dont want to jump into database for data, I already have.

Date format in eloquent models is surprisingly string.

Comment: you can use an attribute accessor I think

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However how can I choose the most closest date from collections of eloquent models? Still I have no idea how to acomplish that.

Comment: Check my answer, I think that's what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what we call in laravel *mutators* like this ->

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    public function dates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Date');
    }

    /**
     * Get Dates for the event.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDates()
    {
        $dates = $this->dates()->getQuery()->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
        return $dates;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

I think now you can also directly do this in the model definition like this -

```
return $this->hasMany('Date')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
```

Comment: getQuery() is your custom function? Just tried this, and Laravel 5.2 fires Method getQuery does not exist. exception. Also, I could not find any mention of getQuery method in official docs. Can you explain please?

Comment: did you try the updated answer? Where I'm calling the orderBy method in the relationship itself? I think getQuery is deprecated from L5...

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works pretty much! Thanks a lot.